# .Net xUnit tests Entity Framework, error when creating tests for a controller with the input UserManager and RoleManager

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, xunit

I'm new to .net so sorry if this is obvious but is this the best approach to test controllers? In this project I'm using the xUnit tests, I create a sql db, using identity framework, I have a controller for my users "Colaboradores" with the crud functions.

I'm doing something wrong, how can I declare correctly the UserManager and RoleManager so I can call them after on Task Index_CanLoadFromContext() without having any problems?

**Code:**

Users controller

```
public class ColaboradoresController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<Colaborador> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public ColaboradoresController(UserManager<Colaborador> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }
        [Authorize(Roles = "PaginaDeColaboradores")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var users = await _userManager.Users.Select(user => new ColaboradoresViewModel
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                Name = user.UserName,
                PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
                Roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result
            }).ToListAsync();

            return View(users);
        }

        //..class continues with more crud functions
```

Test class

```
 public class ApplicationDbContextFixture : IDisposable
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext DbContext { get; private set; }
        public UserManager<Colaborador> UserManager { get; private set; }
        public RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager { get; private set; }
        public ApplicationDbContextFixture()
        {
            var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
            connection.Open();
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .UseSqlite(connection)
                    .Options;
            DbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(options);

            DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            DbContext.Users.Add(new Colaborador { Id = "1", Nome = "admin", Is_admin = true, UserName = "admin", Email = "admin", EmailConfirmed = false });

            DbContext.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole { Id = "1", Name = "EditarColaborador", ConcurrencyStamp = "1" });
            DbContext.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole { Id = "2", Name = "PaginaDeColaboradores", ConcurrencyStamp = "2" });
            DbContext.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole { Id = "3", Name = "EliminarColaborador", ConcurrencyStamp = "3" });
            DbContext.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole { Id = "4", Name = "AtribuirPermissao", ConcurrencyStamp = "4" });
            DbContext.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole { Id = "5", Name = "CriarColaborador", ConcurrencyStamp = "5" });

            DbContext.UserRoles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole<string> { RoleId = "1", UserId = "1" });
            DbContext.UserRoles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole<string> { RoleId = "2", UserId = "1" });
            DbContext.UserRoles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole<string> { RoleId = "3", UserId = "1" });
            DbContext.UserRoles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole<string> { RoleId = "4", UserId = "1" });
            DbContext.UserRoles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole<string> { RoleId = "5", UserId = "1" });

            DbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            DbContext.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

```
public class ColaboradoresControllerTest : IClassFixture<ApplicationDbContextFixture>
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<Colaborador> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public ColaboradoresControllerTest(ApplicationDbContextFixture context)
        {
            _context = context.DbContext;
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            _userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<Colaborador>>();
            _roleManager  = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        }


        [Fact]
        public async Task Index_CanLoadFromContext()
        {
            var controller = new ColaboradoresController(_userManager, _roleManager);

            var result = await controller.Index();

            var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
            var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<Colaborador>>(
                viewResult.ViewData.Model);
            Assert.Equal(model.Count(), 2);
        }
```

[error from running the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGnCO.png)